# How can i start at the exact top of the website in css

Tags: css

i tried to display a bar at the top of the web page but the bar appears about 5 px empty place at the top, right and left sides of the page. The image was 1 black line and i wanted to repeat it from left to right. How can i fix it?

```
       ul.postinge
       {
       width:auto;
       position:relative;
       margin:0cm 0cm 0cm 0 cm;
       display:block;
       height:105px;
       background:url(images/bar.jpg) repeat-x top left;
       }
```

Thanks

Comment: A lot of browsers have a margin on the body element by default. What happens when you add `body { margin:0 }`? (Also, when you're setting margin to 0, you don't need to put the unit `cm`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in some browsers the `body` and or `html` elements have margins or padding. Many experienced CSS developers use CSS resets, but all you should need is:

```
html, body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I typically discourage people from using pre-built CSS resets, as I believe it's more important to have a good understanding of what styles are being set and why. That being said, re-using a core stylesheet that resets styles to the site-specific format *is* a good idea.

That being said, you're liable to come across:

```
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Which *may* help in this particular case, however you're likely going to come across unexpected issues involving forms and tables by using this "simple" style.

Comment: Btw, what does star(*) mean in here?

Comment: @zzzzBov: In what browser `html` has padding/margin?

Comment: @PeeHaa, I don't recall, I've been using that particular style since IE5.5, so it may no longer be necessary.

Comment: @user893970, `*` is a wildcard, which means it matches *every* element. Please review the [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).

Comment: @zzzzBov: hmm. Haven't seen it before. I'll test it tomorrow. Wouldn't surprise me though of IE :)

Answer (score 1):

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Also:

```
margin:0cm 0cm 0cm 0 cm;
```

1. are we really measuring in centimeters?
2. also note the extra space after the last 0

```
ul.postinge { width: auto; position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; display: block; height: 105px; background: url('images/bar.jpg') repeat-x top left; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSS reset like: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

You need to reset the body tag:

```
body {margin:0;padding:0}
```

Using a reset will allow you to "normalize" the margins and padding for your lists as well, among other things

Answer (score 1):

Same as others are saying, only thing I'd add is `list-style` and `border` are other good things to reset too. Generally you never want things unless you specifically specify them.

`* { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; border: none; }`

What `*` does, is it's a wildcard that effects all elements on the page. It can be used in more specific cases as well, for example: if you have container with an id of `container` you could make all elements within it have a red border with the following code:

```
#container * {
    border: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this style in ur css

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

you have to do this because every element has its default margin and padding. By doing this u r setting all elements default padding and margin to zero.